# How can I get a list of files from a server with Transmit?

Tags: amazon-s3, ftp, applescript

Basically I want to upload a file to an Amazon S3 server only if it doesn’t already exist there. I am using Transmit from Panic so I'd like to modify my script to look at the already open S3 session and get the file list, so I can compare it against the new file.

Something like

tell application "Transmit"
    set thelist to contents of current tab of document 1
end tell

(Though this doesn't work. I would either be talking to the tab or to the remote browser session. Can't figure out anything that will achieve this though.)

Can anyone steer me in the right direction? How can I just get the list of files and see if my file is already there, or otherwise do a "smart upload" that only executes if the file isn't already there?

Using version 4.4.10, fully updated Mac.

Answer (score 0):

**AppleScript**

To get you started, Panic has AppleScript examples for Transmit on their support page. One of the three examples is called "Recursive File Listing" and gets you part of the way there: Connecting to a server and listing the file contents. Panic outputs this in a text file, but you can assign the items to a list, check to see if your item is in the list, end if it is or proceed with upload if it isn't.

Here is a direct link to Panic's examples: https://download.panic.com/transmit/Transmit%204%20AppleScript%20Examples.zip

---

**Other Options**

Since you are using Transmit already, you are in luck. It actually already has this function built in!

Go to *Transmit > Preferences > Transfers*. It has options for what to do on uploads and downloads if a file or folder already exists, and one of the options is to skip the upload or download.

[Screenshot of the Transmit Transers menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wq0ve.png)